# nagios check_ping: Invalid hostname/address

Tags: nagios3

I'm trying to setup nagios for a host what has the following webroot: www.example.com/ui/html/, but nagios won't accept as host this kind of host path check_ping: Invalid hostname/address.

Is there a workaround for this issue?

```
# Define a host for the local machine
define host{
        use                     linux-server            ; Name of host template to use
                                                        ; This host definition will inherit all variables that are defined
                                                        ; in (or inherited by) the linux-server host template definition.
        host_name               example.com/ui/html
        alias                   example.com/ui/html
        address                 www.example.com/ui/html/
        }
###############################################################################
###############################################################################
#
# SERVICE DEFINITIONS
#
###############################################################################
###############################################################################
# Define a service to check HTTP on the local machine.
# Disable notifications for this service by default, as not all users may have HTTP enabled.
define service{
        use                             generic-service
        name                            http-service
        service_description             HTTP
        is_volatile                     0
        check_period                    24x7
        max_check_attempts              3
        normal_check_interval           5
        retry_check_interval            1
        notifications_enabled           1
        notification_interval           0
        notification_period             24x7
        notification_options            c,r
        check_command                   check_http!$HOSTADDRESS$
        register 0
     }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure `check_ping` is what you're suppose to use?  The `check_ping` command just validates the availability of a system via an ICMP ping packet.  See  this page for details on it's usage: http://nagiosplugins.org/man/check_ping

Instead, I believe you'll need to use the `check_http` command to verify the web server is responding.  Here is a link to it's usage: http://nagiosplugins.org/man/check_http

From the recently added config file, you have this:

```
define host{
        use                     linux-server
        host_name               example.com/ui/html
        alias                   example.com/ui/html
        address                 www.example.com/ui/html/
        }
```

The `address` and `host_name` lines are incorrect.

- The `host_name` should be `www.example.com`, assuming that's the system name you're hoping to monitor.
- The `address` should be the IP address of the same machine, not the name and portion of the URL.

Both of those notes are based on the information in http://nagios.manubulon.com/traduction/docs25en/macros.html

Comment: I have been removing those lines what are referring to check_ping but shows me the same error